# Passing props from One Screen to Another with createBottomTabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to passing some properties from one screen to another screen through `createBottomTabNavigator`. I am using **react-navigation**.

```
const AppNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home: {screen: HomeScreen}, 
    Map: {screen: MapScreen}
}, {
    initialRouterName: 'Home',
});
```

on HomeScreen I have set the prop with `this.props.navigation.setParams` in `componentDidMount` and if i check this.props.navigation on same screen its displayed properly.

```
componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        position => {
            const location = JSON.stringify(position);
            this.props.navigation.setParams({position: location});
        },
        error => {
            Alert.alert(error.message);
        }, 
        { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 }
    );
}
```

I need to access this props to other screens like `MapScreen` but I am getting null on the other screen.

I am not sure if it is the right way. I know that I can send with `this.props.navigation.navigate` but as you see I am using the **tabNavigator** so not sure where to start.

Comment: try this ..let positiondata = this.props.navigation.getParams('position');

Comment: @Tanveerbyn i tried but ```this.props.navigation.getParams('position')``` give me null

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend to Do with redux rather than passing params.
Redux is meant to share properties from one screen to another.

Answer (score 0):

In Home Component use like this,

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Map',
      {
        name: 'Anand',
        mob : '90090'
      }
    );
```

And in the Map Component, you can use **name** like this.

```
this.props.navigation.state.params.name
```

And in the Map Component, you can use **mob** like this.

```
this.props.navigation.state.params.mob
```

Comment: But how this handled with bottomTabNavigator? if i use ```this.props.navigation.navigate``` it will redirect me to the Map tab on App start.

Comment: Hi Joseph,
For stack navigation  screens and switching between tabs, the API reference does not change anything, For both stack as well as bottomTabNavigation, you can use this.props.navigation.navigate('Map');